# Setting gfortran -fdiagnostics-color

Tags: fortran

I want to use the gfortran  diagnostics-color however I cannot see any colors.

I used this command

`/home/cdim/Local/gcc-4.9.2/bin/gfortran -ffree-form -J./build/lib- -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -o ./bin/test_larsa.x ./utests/test_larsa.f ./lib/larsa.f`

Comment: The [GNU Website](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) says that -fdiagnostics-color is available for the C family, but doesn't mention Fortran. Does color appear when you try to compile a C program?

Comment: Fortran is not yet supported.